# How do I get this url pattern to match?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I'm struggling to match urls with args other than pk. I have a season model that has attributes year and session:

```
 class Season(models.Model):
     season_choices = SEASON_CHOICES
     current = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     year = models.IntegerField(_('year'), choices=year_dropdown, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
     session = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, choices=season_choices)
```

and I want to match urls something like season/year/session.
I have a listview that lists all seasons:

```
 class SeasonList(ListView):
     model = Season
     template_name = 'team/season_list.html'

     def get_queryset(self):
         s = SeasonModel.objects.filter()
         return s
```

and a detailview that's supposed to show the season detail.

```
  class SeasonDetail(DetailView):
     model = Season
     template_name = 'team/season_detail.html'

     def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
         season = get_object_or_404(Season, year=self.kwargs['year'], session=self.kwargs['session'])
         return season
```

- I hadn't originally included this UpdateView which was called Season originally, so that was part of the error.

  ```
   class SeasonUpdate(UpdateView):
   model = Season
   template_name = 'team/season.html'
   form_class = SeasonForm
   success_url = 'success'

   def get_object(self, queryset=None):
       obj = SeasonModel.objects.get(current=True)
       return obj

   def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
       season = SeasonModel.objects.get(current=True)
       context = super(Season,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['games_list'] = GameModel.objects.filter(season=season).order_by('date')
       context['past_seasons'] = Seas.  onModel.objects.filter(current=False).order_by('-year')
       if self.request.POST:
      context['games'] = GameFormSet(self.request.POST)
       else:
      context['games'] = GameFormSet()
       return context

   def form_valid(self, form):
      context = self.get_context_data()
      games = context['games']
      with transaction.atomic():
          self.object = form.save()

          if games.is_valid():
              games.instance = self.object
              games.save()
      return super(Season, self).form_valid(form)
  ```

here are my urls:

```
 url(r'^season/$', team_views.SeasonList.as_view(), name='season_list'),
 url(r'^season/(?P<year>[0-9]{4})/(?P<session>[-\w]+)/$', team_views.SeasonDetail.as_view(), name='season_detail'),
```

and finally my template link:

```
 <a href="{% url 'team:season_detail' year=season.year session=season.session %}">
 <p>{{ season.year }} {{ season.session }}</p></a>
```

- Which was a for loop template error! Got it figured out now.

Comment: Please show the full traceback. I don't think the problem is in this code.

Comment: Did you by any change have overridden the `get(..)` function?

Comment: remove  *args, **kwargs from get_object and try again

Comment: Have you got something else called Season?

Comment: Nope thats the full code that I have for each view.

Comment: You're on to something Daniel I have an update view for Season which was called Season. Changed it to SeasonUpdate, and now getting error 'Season' object is not iterable

Comment: It's hard to correlate the Traceback to the code snippets. But if you get something requesting self - it might be something like a method needs to be defined with `@staticmethod`. I'm not sure best way to link a complete set of python scripts into Stack Overflow so others can reproduce and tweak a more complete example. But if you can find a way to do that - it would probably get you a quicker answer. Perhaps others can comment on such a way..

Comment: Got it now... it was to do with a conflict with my UpdateView name. I would mark yours as the answer Daniel, but don't know how to do so with comments.

Comment: But actually all you guys helped me debug it so good on all of you.